# DBMS: Increase int data type range through trigger

Tags: triggers, database

Some DBMSes, such as MySQL, support different integer types for different range requirements.

For example, for small values, `TINYINT` is preferred while for bigger values, INT may be desirable.

I have a few tables storing trivial data, such as users of an application. While i have planned for the number of users to be in the range of 6,000 therefore choosing to have `SMALLINT`, i would like to cater for the unlikely but possible event that it topples over the maximum range of a `SMALLINT`, 32,767 or 65,535 in the case of unsigned.

Should i implement the logic for checking this through `trigger`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea.  Just use an `int`.

Out of sheer curiosity about what would happen if you did try to alter a table from a trigger on that same table I did just that to see how SQL Server would deal with it.

SQL Server (rightfully) complains:

**Msg 1713, Level 16, State 7, Procedure tgALTERTABLE, Line 10
Cannot execute ALTER COLUMN on/using table 'Test' since the table is the target table or part of cascading actions of a currently executing trigger.**

I would expect most if not all other DBMS platforms to complain about the same since triggers are usually exist as a synchronous part of the data modification transaction being performed.  Altering the underlying table should never work since the operation would require a schema modification lock which cannot be granted until after the transaction that has already been started.

Here is a reference for SQL Server's lock types:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175519%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)